# Scala - grouping on a Map of Maps

Tags: scala

I have a variable that is a `Map[T, Map[Date, Double]]` and I want to turn this into a `Map[Date, List[Double]]` where the date maps to a list of all the doubles that it maps to in the original data structure. I'm having a hard time finding the right combination of functions to get me the structure that I want.

Example:

```
scala> val m1 = Map("2013-01-01" -> 10, "2014-01-01" -> 20)
scala> val m2 = Map("2013-01-01" -> 100, "2014-01-01" -> 200)
scala> val m = Map(1 -> m1, 2 -> m2)
```

Desired result of operation on `m`:

```
Map("2013-01-01" -> List(10, 100), "2014-01-01" -> List(20, 200))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without mutable collections:

```
m.values.
  flatMap{_.seq}.
  groupBy{_._1}.
  map{ case (k, vl) => k -> vl.map{_._2}.toList }
// Map(2014-01-01 -> List(20, 200), 2013-01-01 -> List(10, 100))
```

You could use `mapValues{ _.map{_._2}.toList }` instead of `map{ case (k, vl) => k -> vl.map{_._2}.toList }`, but in this case it will be reevaluated on every access to value.

Using `scalaz`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

m.values.toVector.foldMap{_.mapValues{List(_)}}
```

Comment: +1 to Scalaz! Mike, if you're working with Brian or Chris I bet they'd prefer this answer. Very short, very concise.

Comment: @wheaties: `Very short, very concise` .. very inefficient. `N` `Map` merges.

Comment: lol, well, there is almost always a performance price you pay when you use Scalaz. The real question is, is this in a performance critical area and will the GC pressure play havoc on the rest of the application. That is, if you're I/O capped, who cares? If you're CPU bound, pay attention.

Comment: @wheaties Can you be JIT bound?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a `ListBuffer` otherwise you risk overwriting keys:

```
val builder = MMap[Date, ListBuffer[Double]]
for{
  (_, inner) <- myNested
  (key, value) <- inner
} {
  if(builder contains key) builder(key) += value
  else builder(key) = new ListBuffer(value)
}

builder mapValues(_ result ()) toMap
```

wherein `MMap` refers to a mutable map.